# Calcular gastos por dia e mostrar no gráfico [JQUERY]

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Estou fazendo um trabalho de escola que consiste em implementar um web app (site responsivo mobile first) para armazenar na API Local Storage gastos realizados pelo usuário. Recursos mínimos:

- Adicionar um gasto: descrição, valor, data, categoria (alimentação, vestuário,transporte, lazer, etc.);
- Editar um gasto;
- Remover um gasto;
- Exibir os gastos cadastrados;
- Gráfico de pizza dos gastos por categoria;
- Gráfico de barras dos gastos por dia do mês.

Eu consegui fazer os 5 primeiros recursos, mas no ultimo estou com dificuldade de somar os gastos por dia, pois em vez de somar ele só esta pegando o ultimo gasto cadastrado de uma data. Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

Segue os códigos no JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n2Lwg0jt/

```js
$(function(){
    var operacao = "A"; //"A"=Adição; "E"=Edição
    var indice_selecionado = -1;
    var tbClientes = localStorage.getItem("tbClientes");// Recupera os dados armazenados
    var datas;
    tbClientes = JSON.parse(tbClientes); // Converte string para objeto

    if(tbClientes == null) // Caso não haja conteúdo, iniciamos um vetor vazio
        tbClientes = [];

    $("gasto").on("change",function(){
        $(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2));
    });

    function Adicionar(){
        var data = $("#data").val();
        let split = data.split('-');
        let formated = split[2]+"/"+split[1]+"/"+split[0];

         var cliente = JSON.stringify({
            Descrição: $("#descricao").text(),
            Gasto:     $("#gasto").val(),
            Data:      formated,
            Categoria: $("#categoria").val()
        });
        tbClientes.push(cliente);

        localStorage.setItem("tbClientes", JSON.stringify(tbClientes));

        alert("Registro adicionado.");
        return true;
    }

    function Editar(){
        tbClientes[indice_selecionado] = JSON.stringify({
                Descrição: $("#descricao").val(),
                Gasto:     $("#gasto").val(),
                Data:      $("#data").val(),
                Categoria: $("#categoria").val()
            });
        localStorage.setItem("tbClientes", JSON.stringify(tbClientes));
        alert("Informações editadas.")
        operacao = "A";
        return true;
    }

    function Listar(){
        $("#tblListar").html("");
        $("#tblListar").html(
            "<thead>"+
            "   <tr>"+
            "   <th scope='col'>Descrição</th>"+
            "   <th scope='col'>Gasto</th>"+
            "   <th scope='col'>Data</th>"+
            "   <th scope='col'>Categoria</th>"+
            "   <th scope='col'></th>"+
            "   </tr>"+
            "</thead>"+
            "<tbody>"+
            "</tbody>"
            );
        var soma=0,soma1=0,soma2=0,soma3=0,soma4=0,soma5=0,soma6=0,soma7=0, somaData=[];
        var listaData=[], novaArr=[];
         for(var i in tbClientes){
            var cli = JSON.parse(tbClientes[i]);
            $("#tblListar tbody").append("<tr>"+
                                         "  <td>"+cli.Descricao+"</td>" + 
                                         "  <td>"+cli.Gasto+"</td>" + 
                                         "  <td>"+cli.Data+"</td>" + 
                                         "  <td>"+cli.Categoria+"</td>" + 
                                         "  <td><img src='edit.png' alt='"+i+"' class='btnEditar'/><img src='delete.png' alt='"+i+"' class='btnExcluir'/></td>" +
                                         "</tr>");
            if(cli.Categoria=="Sem categoria")
                soma+= parseFloat(cli.Gasto);
            if(cli.Categoria=="Transferência")
                soma1+= parseFloat(cli.Gasto);
            if(cli.Categoria=="Alimentação")
                soma2+= parseFloat(cli.Gasto);
            if(cli.Categoria=="Casa")
                soma3+= parseFloat(cli.Gasto);
            if(cli.Categoria=="Receita")
                soma4+= parseFloat(cli.Gasto);
            if(cli.Categoria=="Saude")
                soma5+= parseFloat(cli.Gasto);
            if(cli.Categoria=="Transporte")
                soma6+= parseFloat(cli.Gasto);
            if(cli.Categoria=="Vestuário")
                soma7+= parseFloat(cli.Gasto);
            
            listaData.push(cli.Data);           
            novaArr = listaData.filter((este, i) => listaData.indexOf(este) === i);
            
            for(var j in novaArr){
               if(cli.Data == novaArr[j]){
                    somaData[j] = 0;
                    somaData[j]+= somaData[j]+ parseFloat(cli.Gasto);
                }
            }
         }

        let segundoGrafico = document.getElementById('segundoGrafico').getContext('2d');
        let chart2 = new Chart(segundoGrafico, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: novaArr,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Gastos por Dia',
                    data: somaData,
                    backgroundColor: ["#ff2200"]
                }]
            },
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Grafico de Gastos por Dia'
                }
            }
        });

        let primeiroGrafico = document.getElementById('primeiroGrafico').getContext('2d');
        let chart = new Chart(primeiroGrafico, {
            type: 'pie',
            data: {
                labels: ['Sem categoria', 'Transferência', 'Alimentação', 'Casa', 'Receita', 'Saude', 'Transporte', 'Vestuário'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Gastos por Categoria',
                    data: [soma, soma1, soma2, soma3, soma4, soma5, soma6, soma7],
                    backgroundColor: ["#ff2200","#088A08","#0404B4","#6E6E6E","#FFFF00","#3B0B0B","#58D3F7","#74DF00"]
                }]
            },
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Grafico de Gastos por Categoria'
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function Excluir(){
        tbClientes.splice(indice_selecionado, 1);
        localStorage.setItem("tbClientes", JSON.stringify(tbClientes));
        alert("Registro excluído.");
    }

    Listar();

    $("#frmCadastro").on("submit",function(){
        if(operacao == "A")
            return Adicionar();
        else
            return Editar();        
    });

    $("#tblListar").on("click", ".btnEditar", function(){
        operacao = "E";
        indice_selecionado = parseInt($(this).attr("alt"));
        var cli = JSON.parse(tbClientes[indice_selecionado]);
        $("#descricao").text(cli.Descricao);
        $("#gasto").val(cli.Gasto);
        $("#data").val(cli.Data);
        $("#categoria").val(cli.Categoria);
    });

    $("#tblListar").on("click", ".btnExcluir", function(){
        indice_selecionado = parseInt($(this).attr("alt"));
        Excluir();
        Listar();
    });
});
```

```css
img{
 height: 30px;
 width: 30px;
}
canvas{
  max-height: 100% !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
 }

@media (max-width: 320px) {
 .menu { 
  width:calc(200% - 15px); 
  font-size: 12px;
 }

 canvas{
  max-height: 100% !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
 }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>API Web Storage</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Trabalho.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

   
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menu">
        <nav class="navbar-expand">
          <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Gastos por categoria</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Gastos por dia</a>
          </div>
        </nav>
     </div>
        <div class="tab-content container-fluid" id="nav-tabContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
                    <form id="frmCadastro">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="descricao">Descrição:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="descricao" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                           
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="gasto">Gasto:</label>
                                <input type="number" step="0.010" id="gasto" class="form-control">
                            </div>  

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="data">Data:</label>
                                <input type="date" id="data" class="form-control" value="dd/MM/yyyy">
                            </div>
                           
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="categoria">Categoria:</label>
                                <select id="categoria" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="Sem categoria" id="1">Sem categoria</option> 
                                    <option value="Transferência" id="2">Transferência</option>
                                    <option value="Alimentação" id="3">Alimentação</option>
                                    <option value="Casa" id="4">Casa</option> 
                                    <option value="Receita" id="5">Receita</option>
                                    <option value="Saude" id="6">Saude</option>
                                    <option value="Transporte" id="7">Transporte</option>
                                    <option value="Vestuario" id="8">Vestuário</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        
                            
                        <input type="submit" value="Salvar" id="btnSalvar" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">
                    </form>
                    <div class="table-responsive tabela">
                        <table class="table" id="tblListar"></table>    
                    </div>
                    
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
                <canvas id="primeiroGrafico"  width="500" height="550"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">
                <canvas id="segundoGrafico"  width="500" height="550"></canvas>
          </div>
        </div>

        </div>    
   
    
    

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Trabalho.js"></script>
   
    
    
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Melhor criar um [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), pois executar aqui está a dar erro e fica difícil ajudar.

Comment: @iamdlm atualizei o tópico com o link no JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então o problema está no somatório, pois estavas a zerar sempre para cada data mas isso só é preciso fazer para cada primeiro valor. A solução fica assim:

```
if (!somaData[j]) {
 somaData[j] = parseFloat(cli.Gasto);
} else {
 somaData[j] += parseFloat(cli.Gasto);
}
```

Comment: a antiga solução havia dado certo, com essa ele irá somar tudo na primeira data se não me engano

Comment: Essa solução funciona também e é mais "elegante" que a minha anterior. E se resolveu o teu problema marca como a resposta correta por favor